# Upgrade the firmware of SAS HDD on DL380 G5?

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, firmware

I have a DL380 G5 server with 146GB single-port HDD (DG146ABAB).  The HP Storage Array P400 controller is saying that firmware should be upgraded on these drives.  I am running VMware ESX 5.1 (no Windows or Linux).  I have downloaded HP Smart Start Diagnostics but find no help in that tool for flashing the drives..

-Tom V.

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches:

- Download the current [HP Service Pack for ProLiant bootable DVD](http://h17007.www1.hp.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/products/service_pack/spp/index.aspx) and let the system run an automated firmware upgrade of all relevant components.
- Download the [specific .scexe file for your drive and ESXi OS](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=3676017&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=idx%253D0%257CswItem%253DMTX_e11e5507adf240eba4f281244d%257CswEnvOID%253D4115%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D3%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken), and install directly. From VMware's console, wget the file and execute the resulting binary with: `./CP020197.scexe`